# PrivateFontCollection Terrible Quality

Tags: c#, printing, fonts

I am trying to load a font from a file to use when printing for a C# application.

To do this I am loading the font into a `PrivateFontCollection` and the getting the font family from there. Here is a snippet:

```
public void Print(Graphics g)
{
   if (_fontCollection == null)
        LoadFonts();

   FontFamily fontFamily= _fontCollection.Where(f => f.Name == "MyFontName").First();
   Font font = new Font(fontFamily, 12);
   g.DrawString("MyString", font, 10,10);
}

private PrivateFontCollection _privateFontCollection;
private void LoadFonts()
{
    _privateFontCollection = new PrivateFontCollection();
    _privateFontCollection.AddFontFile(@"C:\PathTo\Font\...");
}
```

However the quality is terrible: a screenshot can be found here:

http://snag.gy/1pGWj.jpg

Any idea why this might be???

Comment: Your code assumes that the font is installed.  Otherwise, it's using a default construction.

Comment: Does it? I have clearly misunderstood PrivateFontCollection completely. The fonts are defiantly not installed, nor will they be. How can I use a font from a file without installing?

Comment: I stand corrected.  Perhaps adding to the `Font` constructor the additional parameters `System.Drawing.FontStyle` and `GraphicsUnit.Point`.

Comment: It is perhaps slightly better when specifying `FontStyle` but not by much. I am pretty sure the font files themselves are okay as I am using them in WPF fine. Is there a way to convert between `system.windows.media.fontfamily` and `system.drawing.FontFamily`??

Comment: I doubt that conversion is possible, or would help.  Try setting the `g.TextRenderingHint`.