# Custom Font Rendering Quality Poor

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, fonts, rendering

I am loading a font from ttf file into a `PrivateFontCollection` in my winforms application. I then apply the font to various elements on a form.

```
PrivateFontCollection fonts = new PrivateFontCollection();

private void applyFormFonts()
{
    fonts.AddFontFile("fonts\\OpenSans-Light.ttf");
    fonts.AddFontFile("fonts\\OpenSans-Regular.ttf");

    /// get font family references
    FontFamily openSans = fonts.Families.First(f => f.Name.Equals("Open Sans"));
    FontFamily openSansLight = fonts.Families.First(f => f.Name.Equals("Open Sans Light"));

    /// configure fonts for form components
    this.label1.Font = new Font(openSans, this.label1.Font.Size);
    this.label2.Font = new Font(openSans, this.label2.Font.Size);
    this.textbox1.Font = new Font(openSans, this.textbox1.Font.Size);
    this.button1.Font = new Font(openSansLight, this.button1.Font.Size);
}
```

In all cases, the font loads and is applied to the desired elements. When I test the form on a system that has the font already installed in Windows, the form looks perfect.

However, when I test the form on a system that does not have the form installed, the font displays with very poor quality! The edges are rough and pixels everywhere are missing in action.

I have tried playing with the `UseCompatibleTextRendering` property which is available for some elements (NOT the textbox) and this improves things, a bit.  But why the difference at all!  How can I make these fonts render nicely? Is there a rendering setting for the `Form` itself that I can change?

---

Edit: The suggestion to use the method [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/544637/4267590) didn't *quite* work.  I attempted to create a Font:

```
Font openSans16 = new Font(openSans, 16, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Point);
```

And applied it to the winforms label:

```
this.label1.Font = openSans16;
```

The render quality of the text was the same as previous. The quality was fine if the font was already present in the system, but poor on systems that did not have it installed.

I also tried to use `Graphics.DrawString()` to draw a string in the Paint event handler:

```
private void AlertForm_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    e.Graphics.PageUnit = GraphicsUnit.Point;

    SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
    e.Graphics.DrawString("Test String", openSans16, brush, 120, 100);
}
```

The results, again, were the same. Then in the Paint event handler I tried adding:

```
e.Graphics.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.AntiAliasGridFit;
```

**The results were fantastic! Totally normal looking text.** But to do this directly means I would have to use `DrawString()` for all strings on the form, including multiline text boxes etc.

How can I change the `TextRenderingHint` for rendering of labels and text boxes?

Comment: I have seen this similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21314253/4267590) but I'm not sure how to apply the comments to my situation, if they would be helpful at all. The Q isn't answered.

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/544590/custom-ttf-fonts-to-use-in-c-sharp-windows-form

Comment: Thanks @cFrozenDeath - I've already read that Q/A but I don't think I understand well enough how it applies to this question. Specifically which part of that would you suggest I can use to fix my issue?

Comment: I'd suggest you try the entire code. If you look at the end of the accepted answer, you will see that the fonts render properly (or that seems like). I think that could work for you because you are using TTF files. They might have something special that requires all that work

Comment: There isn't really an indication of how to apply that code to winforms elements like label and textbox, which is what I'm trying to do.  Instead they are drawing strings with Graphics.DrawString().  Not sure how to get from A to B.

Comment: Look at the second code sample, you will see that Font objects are created with specific parameters. You should be able to combine the first and second samples to get the Font objects and assign it to your controls

Comment: Ahh I understand what you're saying now.  Will give that a try...